# How to handle Oracle Long String in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have an OracleDataReader object in vb.net that contains a column holding a Long (which is text in oracle). I need to get it into a datagridview, whenever I try to bind it through a datatable, or convert a single item with .toString I end up with an empty string.

I realize that the column could potentially hold way more text than can be put in the datagrid, I'm okay with cutting off some, or losing some in the conversion because I really only need the first part of it.

Database changes are not an option. Anyone have any knowledge about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> If you use ODP.Net to access an Oracle database from .Net, and select
>   LONG text columns, the DataReader’s GetString() method will return an
>   **empty string**.
>
> To work around this behavior, you need to set the `InitialLONGFetchSize`
>   to a non-zero value, and use the `OracleDataReader‘s` `GetOracleString()`
>   method, and use `ToString()` to convert the result into a .`Net` string.
>
> Another possibility is to set `InitialLONGFetchSize` to -1, so that
>   `GetString()` works as expected.

Found here: http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/08/24/reading-long-oracle-columns-in-net/

Comment: When I try to set it, it says that InitialLONGFetchSize is readonly. Even before I populate the OracleDataReader

Comment: It seems like for the OracleDataReader this is set to readonly, from reading elsewhere